# Copy column data from one sheet to another sheet if values in key column matches

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement

I want to populate the Assessment sheet using data from "Raw data" sheet. The idea is that if a value in column A in "Assessment" matches a value in column A in "Raw data", data from columns B,C,D,E,F,G,H of "Raw data" is copied and pasted to the corresponding columns in "Assessment". The number of rows in both sheets are not the same.
Below is my script:

```
Sub Populate()
    
    Dim ws_copy As Worksheet
    Dim ws_paste As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    
    Call Open_Workbook
    
    
    Set ws_copy = Workbooks("Raw data.xlsx").Sheets("sheet1")
    Set ws_paste = Workbooks("Assessment.xlsx").Sheets("sheet1")
    
    With ws_copy
      
      LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
   
    End With
    
   
   
    With ws_paste
        
        j = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
   
    End With

   For i = 2 To LastRow
   
    With ws_copy
    
        If Application.Match(ws_copy.Range("A:A"), ws_paste.Range("A:A"), 0) <> 0 Then
            .Cells(i, "B").Copy Destination:=ws_paste.Range("C" & j)
            .Cells(i, "C").Copy Destination:=ws_paste.Range("D" & j)
            .Cells(i, "D").Copy Destination:=ws_paste.Range("F" & j)
            .Cells(i, "E").Copy Destination:=ws_paste.Range("G" & j)
            .Cells(i, "F").Copy Destination:=ws_paste.Range("H" & j)
            .Cells(i, "G").Copy Destination:=ws_paste.Range("B" & j)
            .Cells(i, "H").Copy Destination:=ws_paste.Range("E" & j)
        
        
        End If
        
   End With

Next i

End Sub
```

However, I have this error message whenever executing it: "Type mismatch". Can you please help me on this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: In VBA can't use array function. Lookup value has to be  a `Variant` type and contain data.

Comment: is there a way I can check values in column A between 2 sheets instead of using application.match?

Comment: Yes, the `Range.Find` method can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes to conform to VBA.

- Error value has to be tested for no match result.
- Iterate through the Column A values of Raw data.
- Increment `j` counter after copy/paste

```
Sub Populate()
    
    Dim ws_copy As Worksheet
    Dim ws_paste As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    
    Call Open_Workbook
    
    
    Set ws_copy = Workbooks("Raw data.xlsx").Sheets("sheet1")
    Set ws_paste = Workbooks("Assessment.xlsx").Sheets("sheet1")
    
    With ws_copy
      
      LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
   
    End With
    
   
   
    With ws_paste
        
        j = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
   
    End With

   For i = 2 To LastRow
   
    With ws_copy
        On Error Resume Next
        If WorksheetFunction.Match(ws_copy.Range("A" & i), ws_paste.Range("A:A"), 0) <> 0 Then
            If Err <> 0 Then
            Else
            .Cells(i, "B").Copy Destination:=ws_paste.Range("C" & j)
            .Cells(i, "C").Copy Destination:=ws_paste.Range("D" & j)
            .Cells(i, "D").Copy Destination:=ws_paste.Range("F" & j)
            .Cells(i, "E").Copy Destination:=ws_paste.Range("G" & j)
            .Cells(i, "F").Copy Destination:=ws_paste.Range("H" & j)
            .Cells(i, "G").Copy Destination:=ws_paste.Range("B" & j)
            .Cells(i, "H").Copy Destination:=ws_paste.Range("E" & j)
            j = j + 1
            End If
        End If
        On Error Goto 0        
   End With

Next i

End Sub
```