# Copy all data from one worksheet to another worksheet in a right order when a cell value matches using vba

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement

Reference to this post: [Copy column data from one sheet to another sheet if values in key column matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76961389/copy-column-data-from-one-sheet-to-another-sheet-if-values-in-key-column-matches?noredirect=1#comment135673033_76961389)

Hi,
I have 2 excel files: "Sales report" and "Raw data". I want to copy data from "Raw data" to "Sales report" based on Product ID. "Raw data" contains for example 10 Product IDs, however, I want to include info of only 4 product IDs in "Sales report". The original "Sales report" contains only a product id column, other columns have only headers and no data.

Example:
Raw data (note: the first line is the colume's name defaulted by Excel, the second line consists of my headers):

```
A             B       C          D          E                 F             G            H
Product ID    Store   StoreID    Quantity   Price per unit    Total price   CustomerID   Month 
AB001         NY      01         2          5                 10            A135324      04/2023
GHI001        SE      07         1          15                15            Z457246      07/2023
ACA001        CH      03         6          10                60            H293847      06/2023
JF001         OH      02         1          30                30            L293720      03/2023
SSF001        NY      01         8          20                160           B725183      06/2023
BI001         NY      01         2          25                50            J347346      04/2023
LA001         CO      09         3          4                 12            D346435      07/2023
OP001         SE      07         1          250               250           J959942      05/2023
RH001         OH      02         2          3                 6             A562450      04/2023
KQ001         NY      01         10         12                120           C662036      06/2023
```

Sales report is expected to be like this:

```
A             B        C            D       E          F                 G            H
Product ID    Month    CustomerID   Store   StoreID    Price per unit    Quantity     Total price
AB001         04/2023  A135324      NY      01         5                 2            10
OP001         05/2023  J959942      SE      07         250               1            250
ACA001        06/2023  H293847      CH      03         10                6            60
KQ001         06/2023  C662036      NY      01         12                10           120
```

The column order in the 2 files are not the same, and I want to look for product ID in "Raw data", if it matches product ID in "Sales report", data in other columns will be copied and pasted to "Sales report" and in the right order.

Below is my script:

```
Sub Main_content()
    
    Dim ws_copy As Worksheet
    Dim ws_paste As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    Workbooks.Open "C:\HP\Users\Downloads\Raw data.xlsx.xlsx"
    
    
    Set ws_copy = Workbooks("Raw data.xlsx").Sheets("sheet1")
    Set ws_paste = Workbooks("Sales report.xlsx").Sheets("sheet1")
    
    With ws_copy
      
      LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
   
    End With
    

   For i = 2 To LastRow
   
    With ws_copy
    On Error Resume Next
    
        If WorksheetFunction.Match(ws_copy.Range("A" & i), ws_paste.Range("A:A"), 0) <> 0 Then
            .Cells(i, "B").Copy Destination:=ws_paste.Range("D" & i)
            .Cells(i, "C").Copy Destination:=ws_paste.Range("E" & i)
            .Cells(i, "D").Copy Destination:=ws_paste.Range("G" & i)
            .Cells(i, "E").Copy Destination:=ws_paste.Range("F" & i)
            .Cells(i, "F").Copy Destination:=ws_paste.Range("H" & i)
            .Cells(i, "G").Copy Destination:=ws_paste.Range("C" & i)
            .Cells(i, "H").Copy Destination:=ws_paste.Range("B" & i)
        
        Else
            .Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
            
        End If

   End With

Next i

End Sub
```

I'n not very familiar with VBA, so my idea is looping through all cells in column A in "Raw data", if it matches product id specified in "Sales report", all data is then copied, if not, the row in "Raw data" will be deleted. (I know it's not a very good idea as the data should be kept rather than deleted)
However, when I ran my code, all 10 rows in "raw data" were pasted in "Sales report" , some were even in wrong product ids.

Any feedback is highly appreciated!
Many thanks!

Comment: Appears you used the code from the question instead of the answer [Copy column data from one sheet to another sheet if values in key column matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76961389/copy-column-data-from-one-sheet-to-another-sheet-if-values-in-key-column-matches).

Comment: I used the answer. The answer is a slight modification from the question but in the above loop, I utilized only 1 variable i instead of i,j like the reference post. I also added .Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete to the Else statement.

Answer (score 1):

Use the result of `Match()` in the `Destination:=ws_paste.Range("D" & i)` not i.

```vb
Sub Main_content()

    Const RAWDATA = "C:\HP\Users\Downloads\Raw data.xlsx.xlsx"
    Const SALES = "Sales report.xlsx"
    
    Dim wbCopy As Workbook, wbPaste As Workbook
    Dim wsCopy As Worksheet, wsPaste As Worksheet
    Dim rngPaste As Range, m As Variant
    Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long, n As Long
    
    Set wbCopy = Workbooks.Open(RAWDATA)
    Set wsCopy = wbCopy.Sheets("sheet1")
    
    Set wbPaste = Workbooks(SALES)
    Set wsPaste = wbPaste.Sheets("sheet1")
    
    With wsPaste
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngPaste = .Range("A1:A" & lastrow)
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With wsCopy
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1
             m = Application.Match(.Cells(i, "A"), rngPaste, 0)
             If Not IsError(m) Then
                .Cells(i, "B").Copy Destination:=wsPaste.Range("D" & m)
                .Cells(i, "C").Copy Destination:=wsPaste.Range("E" & m)
                .Cells(i, "D").Copy Destination:=wsPaste.Range("G" & m)
                .Cells(i, "E").Copy Destination:=wsPaste.Range("F" & m)
                .Cells(i, "F").Copy Destination:=wsPaste.Range("H" & m)
                .Cells(i, "G").Copy Destination:=wsPaste.Range("C" & m)
                .Cells(i, "H").Copy Destination:=wsPaste.Range("B" & m)
                n = n + 1
            Else
                .Cells(i, "A").Interior.Color = vbRed
                '.Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox n & " rows matched", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! I got this error when executing yours: "Object varaiable or With block variable not set"

Comment: @Laura Which line ? Is C:\HP\Users\Downloads\Raw data.xlsx.xlsx the correct filename ?

Comment: the file's name is correct - Raw data.xlsx (I removed a redundant .xlsx)

Comment: @Laura Which line is the error raised on ?

Comment: Sub Main_content()

Comment: I did a quick search on google and it seems that the root cause lies on set, range ...

Comment: @Laura Use Debug->Step Into and repeat F8 until you get to the line with the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255038/discussion-between-cdp1802-and-laura).